# Terraform - Static ip addresses on Azure

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We have a requirement to configure static private ip's for the vm's that get deployed in Azure via terraform. Tjhe reason is that we then need to use these in Ansible via an ansible pipeline.

One solution I found here was to create a nic with a "dynamic" address first and then convert that to a "static" ip in the next step in Terraform.

```
# Create network interfaces with Private IP's
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = { for vm in var.vms : vm.hostname => vm }
  name                = "${each.value.hostname}-NIC"
  location            = var.network_location
  resource_group_name = var.vm_resource_group
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "monitoringConfg"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.vm_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
  tags = each.value.extra_tag
}

#Convert Dynamic Private IP's to Static
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "staticnic" {
  for_each = { for vm in var.vms : vm.hostname => vm }
  name                = "${each.value.hostname}-NIC"
  location            = var.network_location
  resource_group_name = var.vm_resource_group
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "monitoringConfg"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.vm_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
    private_ip_address            = azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].private_ip_address    
  }
  tags = each.value.extra_tag
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

*A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-NIC" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_network_interface" for more information.
on ../../modules/main.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "staticnic":
58: resource "azurerm_network_interface" "staticnic" {*

Does anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong or a better way to handle this?

Kind Regards,
RB

Comment: Returing to discussion what is ` vm.hostname`? Maybe this has duplicate names and it results in your error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Azure does not assign a Dynamic IP Address until the Network Interface is attached to a running Virtual Machine (or other resource)**, refer to [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface#private_ip_address_allocation). So I think that we can't convert the Dynamic IP to the Static one before the VM created because the IP address does not exist for that time being.

Instead, we could directly associate some static IP addresses to the Azure VM by assigning some IP address in that subnet range. Read [private IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/private-ip-addresses#allocation-method) allocation method.

> Azure reserves the first four addresses in each subnet address range.
> The addresses can't be assigned to resources. For example, if the
> subnet's address range is 10.0.0.0/16, addresses 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.3 and
> 10.0.255.255 are unavailable.

For example, you may refer this template to configure static private ip's for the vms:

```
variable "vmlist" {
  type = map(object({
    hostname = string
    IP_address = string
  }))
  default = {
    vm1 ={
    hostname = "vma"
    IP_address = "10.0.2.4"
    },
    vm2 = {
    hostname = "vmb"
    IP_address = "10.0.2.5"
    }
  }
}

#...

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "staticnic" {
  for_each = var.vmlist
  name                = "${each.value.hostname}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = each.value.IP_address
  }
}

 #...

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each = var.vmlist
  name                  = each.value.hostname
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.staticnic[each.key].id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${each.value.hostname}-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = each.value.hostname
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

   os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = "true"
  }

}
```

I am using

```
Terraform v0.14.7
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.52.0
```

[image]

### Update

If you want to let Azure assign the dynamic IP and then convert it to a static one, you can use [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to invoke a local executable after a resource is created.

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {

  for_each = var.vmlist
    provisioner "local-exec" {

   command = <<EOT

      $Nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName ${azurerm_resource_group.main.name} -Name ${azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].name}
      $Nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAllocationMethod = "Static"
      Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic
   EOT
   
   interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  
  }
}
```

Comment: If so, you can use PowerShell scripts to manage it as my update.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, that looks promising. I tried that but i get the error: ': exec: "PowerShell": executable file not found in $PATH. Output:. I am using an Ubuntu Azure Agent. i even tried pwsh instead of powershell as an interpreter.

Comment: I have Azure-pipelines.yml file with the validate and deploy stages (for terraform) followed by a powershell script to copy hosts file from agent. I don't think i can run the powershell script in the Yaml file, after the deploy as the pipeline is not aware of the variables/ip addresses generated by terraform. Running it inline would make more sense as I can use the variables. Any other pointers to finish this? this is the last sticking point for me.

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure-DevOps service. The above script can work well on my local windows machine. For ubuntu agent, if  az CLI installed on that agent, you can run the cli command with provisioner "local-exec"`az network nic ip-config update -g <rgname> --nic-name <nicname> --name <ipconfig1> --set privateIpAllocationMethod="Static"`, read [this](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1046) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Nancy. I ended up with the following: changed pool vmImage to be windows-latest. in the main.tf , in the null resource i added the following `az login --service-principal --username ${var.APP_ID} --password ${var.SP_PASSWORD} --tenant ${var.TENANT_ID} az network nic ip-config update -g ${var.vm_resource_group} --nic-name ${azurerm_network_interface.publicnic[each.key].name} --name ${var.nic_ip_config} --set privateIpAllocationMethod="Static"` and finally, a null resource with `az logout`. All resources used `interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]`

Answer (score 1):

For ease of reading this is what was done.

First, i created a service principle in azure using the steps listed here [Creating a Service Principal](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#creating-a-service-principal)

**variables.TF**

The command outputs were added to variables.TF as

```
variable APP_ID {
  default = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
variable SP_PASSWORD {
  default = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
variable TENANT_ID {
  default = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This service principal variables will be used to do the *az login* before running the *az network* command on the windows worker agent.

**Main.TF**

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = { for vm in var.vms : vm.hostname => vm }
  name                = "${each.value.hostname}-NIC"
  location            = var.network_location
  resource_group_name = var.vm_resource_group
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = var.nic_ip_config
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.vm_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
  tags = each.value.extra_tag
}
```

To convert the above dynamic ip's tp static

```
# Convert All Private IP's from Dynamic to Static using powershell
resource "null_resource" "StaticIPsPrivateVMs" {
  for_each = { for vm in var.vms : vm.hostname => vm }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = <<EOT
      az login --service-principal --username ${var.APP_ID} --password ${var.SP_PASSWORD} --tenant ${var.TENANT_ID}
      az network nic ip-config update -g ${var.vm_resource_group} --nic-name ${azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].name} --name ${var.nic_ip_config} --set privateIpAllocationMethod="Static"
      EOT
    interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_machine.vm
  ]
}

#AZ logout
resource "null_resource" "AzLogout" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = <<EOT
      az logout
      EOT
    interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.StaticIPsPrivateVMs
  ]
}
```

**Azure-pipelines.yml**

I added *vmImage: 'windows-latest'* at the top of the **validate** and **deploy** stages so that we don't end up using linux agents which will throw powershell not found errors:

```
  - stage: validate
    jobs:
    - job: validate
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      continueOnError: false
      steps:
```

```
- stage: deploy
    jobs:
    - deployment: deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      continueOnError: false
```

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a misconception about what "dynamic" means for a private IP in Azure. Creating a NIC in Azure with a "dynamic" private ip means the IP is assigned upon creation of the interface and only freed upon deletion of the interface.

This means it behaves exactly as "static" interfaces.

The only difference is that a "static" interface has a user assigned (as in input parameter) IP, a "dynamic" interface is automatically assigned a free IP from the subnet. I have send a PR to update the tf docs https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/15264

( From https://stackoverflow.com/a/70998327 )

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to depend on local-execs. You can also use the [azApi](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs), docs on the [Azure site too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/overview-azapi-provider)

What this basically does is do a rest-api call but with terraform credentials. Otherwise you still have to login with az login before you run terraform. Also not handy.

In our case we create a nic, then a virtual machine and then after the virtual machine is created we change the value of **Dynamic** to **Static**

An example piece for the azapi update:

```
resource "azapi_update_resource" "static_ip_linux" {
  count = var.os_flavor == "linux" ? 1 : 0
  type = "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-08-01"
  body = local.body_static_ip_encoded_json
  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.linux_vm]
}
```

We have 2 flavors windows and linux hence the difference with count and depends on.

The body is created in the locals section and looks in our case like this:

```
  body_static_ip_encoded_json = jsonencode({
   "properties":{
      "ipConfigurations": [
        {
          "name": "${var.name}-ipconfig",
          "properties": {
            "privateIPAddress": "${azurerm_network_interface.nic[0].private_ip_addresses[0]}",
            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
            "subnet": {
              "id": data.azurerm_subnet.snet.id
            }
          }
        }
      ]
   },
   "location": "${var.location}"
  })
```

Don't forget to add to your **versions.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}
```

This is needed so your module knows which provider to use. Otherwise if you `terraform init` it can complain about hashicorp/azapi (and it should be azure/azapi)

Read the docs for the default `required_provider` bit, which is the same as the default azurerm.

This works for all items that are not included yet with Terraform but do work via Rest API calls. (Azure preview for example, only when it is final will they usually update the rest/az cli commands)