# Azure VM Convert Dynamic IP to Static Using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

My customer would like to convert the private IP addresses that are dynamically assigned to their VM NICs to static using the address that was dynamically assigned using the Azure RM Terraform providers. I've seen examples in ARM where the NIC to static is in a nested ARM template but how can that be done using Terraform?

Our initial attempts at converting the private IP dynamic address to static results in our VM composition creating two NICs even if the previous name of the NIC is used.

Is there a way to update the NIC configuration without running the composition twice?

Appreciate any thoughts on this.
Bryan

Comment: Do you have code you can share?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform - provision static ip addresses on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281917/terraform-provision-static-ip-addresses-on-azure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a dynamic private IP address to a static one, we could invoke scripts with terraform to manage it because Azure does not assign a Dynamic IP Address until the Network Interface is attached to a running Virtual Machine (or other resource).

For example, you can use local-exec Provisioner to invoke a local executable after a resource is created.

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {

    provisioner "local-exec" {

   command = <<EOT

      $Nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName ${azurerm_resource_group.main.name} -Name ${azurerm_network_interface.nic.name}
      $Nic.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAllocationMethod = "Static"
      Set-AzNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic
   EOT
   
   interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  
  }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678399/terraform-static-ip-addresses-on-azure/66702294#66702294) is an answer I post before you may get references.

Comment: How can we use a local provisioner if Terraform Enterprise is used? I like the idea though.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used the Terraform Enterprise, you may ask the support for it [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/support/index.html).

Comment: According to Terraform's documentation using a null provider and using local-exec is a bad idea because it might mess up the state, not to mention installing additional software onto the TFE container is risky as well. 
(https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/run/install-software.html#avoid-installing-extra-software).

Comment: If you don't use local-exec, you could directly assign the static IP to the nic like my linking answer. As far as I know, there is not a better method to directly convert dynamic Ip to static.

Comment: When using local-exec provisioner if we use AZCLI or PowerShell to convert the NIC to static how would that effect how TFE manages the state of the VM?

Comment: Based on my experiences, the effect is less, the local-exec provisioner can be included in a [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource). The null_resource can be managed by your Terraform state file. Instances of null_resource are treated like normal resources, but they don't do anything, refer to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/null_resource.html).